# GSM Module + RS485 transceiver possible?

Tags: rs485, gsm

I was wondering if someone could confirm if it is feasible to interface a GSM module for example SIM900, SIM900, Quectel's M95 or Neoway's N10 , maybe if we use the RS232 interface with HW the flow control pins RTS/DTR to the MAX485 or equivalent to talk to a master RS485 node ? or do i need to use a microcontroller to handle that job ?

Comment: I can't be bothered to go search for the datasheets. If it has UART interface then yes you can use RS-485. If it actually has RS-232, the design is outdated and the product should be avoided. No MCU needed in either case, it's just hardware signal levels.

Comment: What got me suspicious is i never saw an RS485 GSM modem without having its own microcontroller, that got me intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** definitely. You **do not need another micro controller** for that. 
Any product with UART can be brought out on RS485, with a level converter like [this](http://www.ti.com/product/THVD1451):
[image]